# Convergence of a binary sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

There is an infinite sequence $\{a_n\}$, and it is known that every element is either $0$ or $1$.

Prove or disprove that the following limit exists:

$$ \lim_{N\to\infty} {\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{N}{a_n}}{N}}$$

WHAT I TRIED:

The function under the limit is obviously bounded between $0$ and $1$. This means that, if the limit exists, it must be between $0$ and $1$. But, this does not prove that the limit exists.

I read about various [convergence tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests), but, it seems that these tests relate to series, and my limit is not exactly a series (the series of the $a_n$ obviously does not converge).

I tried to compare the limit to the definition of a definite integral of a certain function. But, I don't know how I can prove that the function is integrable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The limit need not exist. The idea is to have a $1$, then $4$ $0$'s, then $16$ $1$'s, then $64$ $0$'s, then $256$ $1$'s, and so on. The partial sums, divided by $N$, bounce around a lot. Since it is homework, details are left to you. You can modify the $1,4,16,64,256, \dots$ to a much faster growing sequence, which may make calculation easier.

Comment: OK, I see. After each group of 0's the argument drops to at most 1/3, and after each group of 1's the argument rises to at least 2/3, therefore there can be no limit.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I chose the going up by $4$'s to get the $1/3,2/3$. We can even go up so fast that the liminf is $0$ and the limsup is $1$.